# Finding the total number of values in a text file java

Tags: java, filereader, readline

I have a text file that I have to use in my program. I have already created 
a file reader to display the contents of the file. However, I don't want to display all of the content but display the number of words.

For example, my file named database is a file that displays the priceof each individual and has four lines that display the name, age, activity and the price. I want to create a report which shows the total number of basketball players and total number of soccer players and then display the average price.

Here is my code so far:

```
String fileName = "database.txt";

try {
  FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
  BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
  while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {

   }
  }
```

How can I count and add the total values of basketball as well as soccer for the output as well as obtaining each fee and calculating the total and average?

Comment: What happened? Does the solution became irrelevant for you now? Why did you remove the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can the try the below code. You can split the lines from file with whitespace and use them. I have used an if condition in else part, because if any other type of sport comes in the file.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Player {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int basketballCount = 0;
    int soccerCount = 0;
    double basketballFee = 0.0;
    double soccerFee = 0.0;

    BufferedReader read  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("database.txt"));
    String line;
    while ((line = read.readLine()) != null) {
      String parts[] = line.split(" ");
      if (parts[3].equals("basketball")) {
        basketballCount++;
        basketballFee = basketballFee + Double.parseDouble(parts[4]);
      } else if (parts[3].equals("soccer")) {
        soccerCount++;
        soccerFee = soccerFee + Double.parseDouble(parts[4]);
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Total Player: "+basketballCount + "\tTotal Fee: " + basketballFee + "\tAvg Fee:" + basketballFee/basketballCount);
    System.out.println("Total Player: "+soccerCount + "\tTotal Fee: " + soccerFee + "\tAvg Fee:" + soccerFee/soccerCount);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [String#split()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm). Essentially, the code will look like this:

```
String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
double value = Double.valueOf(tokens[4]);
String sport = tokens[3];
```

Then you can do whatever you want to those values. The official documentation for the method:

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.
>   This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array
>
> **Returns**:
>   the array of strings computed by splitting this string around matches of the given regular expression

Answer (score 0):

This code reads the file using Scanner and then finds average of basketball fee and soccer fee it is self explanatory if there is any please comment

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StackOverflow 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("database.txt"));
        int basketball = 0;
        int soccer = 0;
        double basketfee = 0.0, soccerfee = 0.0;
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) 
       {
           String line = sc.nextLine();
           if (line.contains("basketball")) 
           {
                basketball++;
                String fee = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(' '));
                fee = fee.trim();                                
                basketfee = basketfee + Double.parseDouble(fee);
           }
           else if (line.contains("soccer")) 
           {
               soccer++;
               String fee = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(' '));
               fee = fee.trim();
               soccerfee = soccerfee + Double.parseDouble(fee);
           }
       }
       System.out.println("Average fee for basketball is " + basketfee / basketball);
       System.out.println("Average fee for soccer is " + soccerfee / soccer);
   }

}
```